# SQL Stored procedure to delete all questions and answers for a particular test

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

In my SQL Server 2008 database i have three tables:

- Test(TestId int, TestName varchar(50), UserId int, UserType int, isDelete bit)
- Questions(Tid int, Qid int, Qtype int, Question varchar(100), isDelete bit)
- Answers(questionid int, qtype int, description varchar(200), isDelete bit)

`TestId` is available in Questions table and not in answers table.
Whenever I delete a record the isDelete field is updated to true.

Now I want to delete a test i.e all questions from that test and all answers for those questions must be deleted but I cannot get the SP to delete Test
I am new to programming.

Comment: Try using `triggeres`

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, any issues you faced etc.

Comment: I would not use triggers for something like this. You can either delete the rows in correct order (answer, question, test) or use foreign keys with `on delete cascade`

Comment: on delete cascade should be removed from any database. Use a trigger for this

Comment: @GuidoG your comment is a bit obtuse to me. Why should delete cascade be removed and instead use a trigger?

Comment: @SeanLange When you setup a foreign key using the designer in stead of in code, it always enables it. That should be removed. Also using trigger is better imo because you have some extra control, like doing some checkes before deleting

Comment: I never use the designer to create foreign keys. I always do this in code. Regardless it isn't something that should be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Delete Answers from Answers
inner join Questions on
Questions.Qid = Answers.questionid
inner join Test on
Test.TestId = Questions.Tid
where Test.TestId = @Id
and Test.isDelete = 1

Delete Questions from Questions 
inner join Test on
Test.TestId = Questions.Tid
where Test.TestId = @Id
and Test.isDelete = 1

Delete Test where TestId = @Id
and isDelete = 1
```

With the joins you can connect `Test` with `questions` using `TestId` and then `Questions` with `Answer` using `Qid` and it will delete all records in those tables that matches de conditions.

Comment: HUH??? You can't delete from three tables in a single delete statement like this.

Comment: Wow, if this the accepted answer, I must have completely misunderstood this part of the original question:  "Whenever I delete a record the isDelete field is updated to true."

Answer (score 1):

You're doing "soft deletes" so ignore all the confusion about triggers and cascades and order of operations.  Use joins to find out which ones belong to the test you are deleting from.

Comment: This is the actual answer in my opinion.  Triggers are bad news, just write simple queries and delete items in the correct order.  Done.